# mapFragment.getMap() returns null

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-play-services, supportmapfragment

I'm trying to get a map from a SupportMapFragment but it returns null. From what I read this could be because the fragment is not yet fully displayed and therefore no map exists?! I tried fixing it using executePendingTransactions() but with no success so far.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Here is the code

```
private GoogleMap map;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    //...
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState ); 
    setContentView( R.layout.screen_mission2 );
    GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();

    mapOptions.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
        .compassEnabled(true)
        .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
        .tiltGesturesEnabled(false);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
    mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapFragment, mapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    myFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    if(mapFragment == null) Base.log("mapFragment==null");
    if(map==null){
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        Base.log("map should have been initialized");
        if(map==null) Base.log("map still null");
    }
}
```

And the layout file:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

It returns the following log

```
V/FragmentManager(24224): add: SupportMapFragment{4078c4b8 id=0x7f06003d}
V/FragmentManager(24224): Allocated fragment index SupportMapFragment{4078c4b8 #1 id=0x7f06003d}
V/FragmentManager(24224): moveto CREATED: SupportMapFragment{4078c4b8 #1 id=0x7f06003d}
D/EMR     (24224): map should have been initialized
D/EMR     (24224): map still null
```

Comment: Here have you declared the `mapFragment` variable?

Comment: Yes the I declared it(edited the code part, see above)

Comment: Is it initialized? Otherwise it will be the same as nothing, i.e., `null`.

Comment: doesn't mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions); take care of that? At least if(mapFragment == null) Base.log("mapFragment==null"); doesn't appear in the log

Answer (score 14):

Try moving all code that references your `GoogleMap` to `onStart()` or `onResume()`. The map in a map fragment isn't instantiated until after the fragment has gone through `onCreateView` ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMap%28%29)), which happens after the parent activity has gone through `onCreate()`. Also, you need to check your `GoogleMap` for `null` regardless, because if google play services aren't installed, or the map isn't available for some other reason, it will be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I read this could be because the fragment is not yet fully displayed and therefore no map exists?

Correct.

> Any ideas how to fix it?

Actually use the layout file, by calling `setContentView()`, and get rid of all the `FragmentTransaction` stuff. You can then retrieve the already-created `SupportMapFragment` and use it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

SupportMapFragment mapFrag=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that but can I set the options specified in GoogleMapOptions in my code then in the xml file or set them later?

Comment: @cos4: There are equivalents in the XML, though some people have reported issues when using those in Eclipse due to some Eclipse/ADT bug. If that does not work, get rid of the `SupportMapFragment` in the XML, replacing it with a `FrameLayout`, stick with your existing `FragmentTransaction` (pouring the fragment into the `FrameLayout`), but then you need to delay your work with the `GoogleMap` for a bit (e.g., subclass `SupportMapFragment` and put your code in `onActivityCreated()`).

Comment: Is there any doc on setting options for maps in XML? Couldn't find any...  Otherwise if I have to subclass SupportMapFragment anyway I could also send an intent from onActivityCreated() and catch it from my current activity?!

Comment: @cos4: "Is there any doc on setting options for maps in XML?" -- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#configuring_initial_state  "I could also send an intent from onActivityCreated() and catch it from my current activity?" -- I don't see how, or what good that it would do you. If you create your own `SupportMapFragment` subclass, delegate configuration of the map to the subclass.

Comment: Thanks! The idea was: I need to wait until the SupportMapFragment activity is created, so I would modify onActivityCreated() to send me an intent telling me that I can now created a map object since SupportMapFragment is ready.

Comment: @cos4: Since your fragment is already part of your activity, just call a method on the activity. No need to mess with `Intent`s.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks that would be an option. However using the XML options I do get a map (need to use Project->clean to get rid of the Eclipse bug) but I get a white map and _Process com.google.android.apps.maps:GoogleLocationService (pid 4604) has died._ Dunno if that is related though.

Comment: @cos4L: Don't know what to tell you about that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `OnMapReadyCallback`, define its `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)` and use it to operate on the fragment as stated in the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback)