# android (Support)MapFragment getMap() return null

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapfragment

I allready read a lot topics about this problem but nothing helped.
So I want to operate on a GoogleMap in a SupportMapFragment. In the FragmentActivity I initialized the map in the onCreate Method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);

    // Initialize Google Maps Android API
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
...
```

the Code of my MapFragment looks exactly like this

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, null);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    GoogleMap gMap = this.getMap();

    Log.d(TAG,
            "getMap() " + ((gMap == null) ? "null" : gMap.toString()));

    // Setting Location and Zoom
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
            40.76793169992044f, -73.98180484771729f), 14.0f));
}

}
```

Every time I am getting null with the getMap Method... any ideas?

€dit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:cameraBearing="112.5"
map:cameraTargetLat="-33.796923"
map:cameraTargetLng="150.922433"
map:cameraTilt="30"
map:cameraZoom="50"
map:mapType="normal"
map:uiCompass="false"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="false"
map:uiTiltGestures="true"
map:uiZoomControls="false"
map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
```

Comment: is there a map in your layout ?

Comment: Not directly. I have a fragment layoutfile. See it in the edited post.

Comment: Have you tried moving your getMap() code to onStart or onResume?  See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20747717/2364687, although it might not apply in your case.  Also, you definitely have Google Play Services installed (ie, you're not catching and ignoring the exception in onCreate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faced with similiar issue, after updating google play services to the latest version.
my problem was resolved by adding metadata in manifest

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map