# fm.getMap() returns null in Android Maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-studio

My android google maps app crashes of a null pointer exception because the Support Fragment Map object is not getting created.
Please help me diagnose the issue that is causing this.
Apparently everyone has a different issue that causes this so the repeated question:

here is my code:-

```
    package com.iiitk.zeda.flashcabs;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.iiitk.zeda.flashcabs.DirectionsJSONParser;


public class Home extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
TextView tvDistanceDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

    // Initializing 
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
   SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


  // MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

while(fm==null) {
    int a=10;
}

    map = fm.getMap();
    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    //map = fm.getMap();

    // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Setting onclick event listener for the map
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            // Already two locations                
            if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                markerPoints.clear();
                map.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(point);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);

            /**
             * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
             * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
             */
            if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }


            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            map.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }

        }
    });

}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}



// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";



        if(result.size()<1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }


        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

        }

        tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mapFragment.getMap() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771545/android-mapfragment-getmap-returns-null).

Answer (score 0):

After `findFragmentById(R.id.map);` put this code below:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        map = fm.getMap();
        if(map == null) new Handler().postDelayed(this, 500);
        else {
            // Do setup the map
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

This will try to get the `Map` instance every 500ms until it is not null.

**NOTE:** `SupportMapFragment fm` should be a final variable or a member variable of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to getMap() will be null until the fragment has gone through the onCreateView lifecycle stage, so you can't call it in `onCreate()`, you need to call it in `onCreateView()`

Here is the section of the relevant section of the doc as well as a link.

```
public final GoogleMap getMap ()
```

Gets the underlying GoogleMap that is tied to the view wrapped by this fragment.
     Returns the GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet ready. This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap()